# Pointing secondary DNS to another server

Tags: hosting, domain-name-system

I have a domain name and two hosting accounts on different servers.

I would like to know can i park my domain in both hostings and point this domain's primary and secondary nameservers to these two servers, so that if one server is down, files from another server are opened?

Comment: your question is unclear - DNS servers host domain name information, not files.

Comment: saying server i mean my hosting server not DNS server

Comment: That doesn't answer Alnitak's question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it *quite* [works that way](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/server-management-97/nameservers-backup-hosting-account-287948.html). DNS servers have no way of checking whether or not your hosting is down, all they do is provide IP for domains.
You could use some [automated service](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/s0306/price/dns.html) to achieve [such a goal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_robin_DNS), but I don't think the basic protocol itself is going to support it out of the box. It all depends on your DNS provider's capabilities.

Comment: i've just contacted my domain name provider and their technical assistant said that this will work just fine: if the server is faild to be reached by address provided by first nameserver the others will be used (again the order is random)! But i can't say if it is DNS-server-dependent or not.

Comment: Either your domain name provider is lying to you, or they're answering a different question than the one you asked here.  What you want and suggest in your question will *not* work.

Comment: The only way that would work is if their servers are checking your hosting status and altering the DNS records, like some services do. Note that you'll still get hosed by DNS caching and TTL.

Answer (score 0):

DNS does not provide (automated) *fail over*, it only supports *load distribution*.

It's technically possible to have a DNS system which polls your servers to check which are working, and then directs traffic accordingly, but you won't get that from an off-the-shelf DNS hosting provider.

In any event, the DNS protocol simply isn't designed to handle rapid changes based on network level faults.